# Sitecore Update NameValueList Programmatically

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

Is there anyway to update NameValueList field?

I want to find a key and update its value programmatically.
Here is what I tried, but not working.

[image]

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.NameValueListField data = Model.Rendering.Item.Fields["Name Value List"];
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = data.NameValues;

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    Model.Rendering.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    nameValueCollection.Set("123456", "New Value");
    Model.Rendering.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Any help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `NameValueListField` in dotPeek, the `NameValues` property does not pass a reference to the underlying data, but rather an object containing the parsed values. If you make a change to the `NameValueCollection`, you need to set it back on the field. So something like this:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.NameValueListField data = Model.Rendering.Item.Fields["Name Value List"];
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nameValueCollection = data.NameValues;

using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    Model.Rendering.Item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    nameValueCollection.Set("123456", "New Value");
    data.NameValues = nameValueCollection;
    Model.Rendering.Item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Unrelated: You appear to be editing a value in a Sitecore MVC rendering. Keep in mind a couple things:

- By default, this will be the web database, and the values will be overwritten on publish
- Writing to the Sitecore database is very slow and usually a bad idea in public-facing web pages that may be under even minor amounts of traffic load

Comment: Oh, I double checked again and it works. And the posed code is sample code to prevent complexity. I don't definitely add this code in production.